# Question on Series Transformations from "The Harmonic Series and Logarithmic Intragrals"

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is from an example in Section 1.7 of the book, "The Harmonic Series and Logarithmic Integrals" by, Ali Shadhar Olaikhan

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \mathcal{J}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n^3}$$

I don't understand how the left side of this example has any Complex terms.  It appears to be entirely Real.  What am I not understanding, please?

Comment: The picture of your example seems to be missing- we can't see what you're referring to.

Comment: It appears that it's taking the imaginary part of the sum.  By definition, the imaginary part will be real, and you get the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\Im \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{i}^n}{n^3}
&= \Im \left( \frac{\mathrm{i}^1}{1^3} + \frac{\mathrm{i}^2}{2^3} + \frac{\mathrm{i}^3}{3^3} + \frac{\mathrm{i}^4}{4^3} + \cdots \right)  \\
&= \Im \frac{\mathrm{i}^1}{1^3} + \Im \frac{\mathrm{i}^2}{2^3} + \Im \frac{\mathrm{i}^3}{3^3} + \Im \frac{\mathrm{i}^4}{4^3} + \cdots   \\
&= \frac{1}{1^3} + 0 + \frac{-1}{3^3} + 0 + \cdots   \\
\end{align*}